# jqueryrotate works with IE7 and IE8, but not IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Nice little plugin to rotate stuff: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

This was a good example which works on IE7, IE8, FF, Chrome, etc, etc on how to make it work as a clock: http://d-zig.com/demo/46e3ec48-0f71-4615-8798-61cd83266659/

It doesn't work with IE6, but I am not surprised or disappointed.

The disappointing and surprising part is it works with earlier versions of IE, but not IE9!

Here is an initial jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KurKa/

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless I am not understanding what your example is supposed to do, your jsfiddle appears to be working for me in IE9.

Comment: Yes, the jsfiddle version, but what about the link at http://d-zig.com/demo/46e3ec48-0f71-4615-8798-61cd83266659/ (or just upload the jsfiddle code to your server and try it out)

Comment: It is most likely because they are using jquery 1.4.1. I have experienced issues with several plugins in IE 9 when the are using later version of jquery.

Comment: Jquery did not support IE9 until version 1.5.1. That is why the demo does not work, but your jsfiddle does. I have put more information regarding this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source of http://d-zig.com/demo/46e3ec48-0f71-4615-8798-61cd83266659/, and it was using jquery 1.4.1 which could possibly explain why it does not work but your fiddle does. I believe this is most likely because your fiddle was using jquery 1.7.2.

In the past, I have had experience with several jquery plugins that would not work in IE9 because I was using an older version of jquery. If you upgrade jquery, the problem should be resolved.

Edit: I believe my assumptions are correct. Jquery did not support IE9 until version 1.5.1. This information can be found [in a blog post for the release of jquery 1.5.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/02/24/jquery-151-released/)

Comment: My main webpage is using current jquery, but is still having problems.  I created a quick demo site with recent jquery, and it worked fine.  Your answer is correct, and it appears I have different issues.  Thank you, and hopefully I will find my problem soon!

Comment: You may want to create a separate question for your current issues. Someone may be able to find your problem. It could be something as simple as a conflict with some others scripts you are running. Good luck!